# React - How to Populate two Dropdowns based on selection in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I need to change the contents of dropdown Method&Minorhead based on the selection in dropdown MajorHead using React.

If I select cheating in majorhead, then it's supposed to show a&b in minorHead and apple, orange in Method.

If I select abduction in majorhead, then it's supposed to show AB&BC in minorhead and cat, dog in Method...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Profile extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="inputState">Major head</label>
                    <select id="inputState" className="form-control"/>
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        <option>Cheating</option>
                        <option>Abduction</option>
                        <option>House brake</option>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="inputState">Minor head</label>
                    <select id="inputState" className="form-control"/>
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        <option>a</option>
                        <option>b</option>
                        <option>AB</option>
                        <option>BC</option>
                        <option>X</option>
                        <option>Y</option>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="inputState">method</label>
                    <select id="inputState" className="form-control"/>
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        <option>apple</option>
                        <option>orange</option>
                        <option>cat</option>
                        <option>dog</option>          
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
export default Profile;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each option in your major head Select, i would create an array of supported values for method and minor.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedView: 'Cheating'
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    const { selectedView } = this.state
    const VIEWS = [
      {
        name: 'Cheating', 
        minor: ['a', 'b'], 
        method: ['apple', 'orange']
      }, {
        name: 'Abductions', 
        minor: ['AB', 'BC', 'X'], 
        method: ['cat', 'dog']
      }
    ]

    const getMajorMethod = () => {
      const view = VIEWS.filter(({name}) => name === selectedView)[0]
      return (
        <div>
          <select>
            {view.minor.map(m => <option>{m}</option>)}
          </select>
          <select>
            {view.method.map(m => <option>{m}</option>)}
          </select>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={(e) => this.setState({selectedView: e.target.value})}>
          {VIEWS.map(({name}) => <option value={name}>{name}</option>)}
        </select>

        {getMajorMethod()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

A structure like this will allow you to (within your initial MAJOR select) `map` over your `VIEWS` and apply the `name` prop to the options.

You can then have another map that shows two other selects (minor & method) with the `VIEWS` relative `minor` and `method` arrays being their options

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 18
}

Comment: You'll also notice that i don't declare a react component either... 

This is an example of my logic.

Comment: @FrancisLeigh Your solution is better than mine, I have modified it to make it runnable. Please review my edit

Comment: @kasim521 Sorry for the laziness, Kevin Qian went the extra mile with the edit :-)

Comment: If this is the answer you wanted then please mark as such.

Comment: `VIEWS.filter(({name}) => name === selectedView)[0]` why the [0] and why put ({name}) ?

Comment: @omar object destructuring. Name is a prop of the object being passed to the iteration.

Comment: so you did that instead of doing  `VIEWS.filter(item) => item.name === selectedView)`

Comment: Correct, and with regards to your query about [0] - I didn't put that, I think Kevin did. I would think that is because 
.filter returns an Array and we want the first item of that array (the object returned from our name query)