# React throwing TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'view.states')

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
    countryVal:''
    };

    this.handleChange3 = this.handleChange3.bind(this);
  };

   handleChange3(event){
    this.setState({countryVal:event.target.value});

  }

      render() {

      const {countryVal} = this.state
      const VIEWS = [
      {
        country: 'India', 
        states: ['Kerala', 'Karnataka','Tamil nadu'] 
      }, {
        country: 'America', 
        states: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
      }, {
        country: 'Africa', 
        states: ['test4', 'test5', 'test6']
      }
    ]

    const getMajorMethod = () => {
        const view = VIEWS.filter(({country}) => country === countryVal )[0]
        return(
            <select id="stateSelectId"  style={{'width':'150px','display':'block'}}>
                {view.states.map(m => <option>{m}</option>)}
            </select>

        )
    }     

      return (
      <div>
        <div style={{'border':'1px solid gray','padding':'20px','margin':'20px'}}>
            <select  onChange={this.handleChange3} style={{'width':'150px'}}>
                {VIEWS.map(({country}) => <option value={country}>{country}</option>)}
            </select>
            <br/><br/>
            {getMajorMethod()}
        </div>


     </div> 
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I'am trying to implement react app where state dropdown gets changes on selecting country dropdown.

but i'am facing issue in loading states to select menu.
its throwing "React throwing TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'view.states')"

on removing the "{getMajorMethod()}" its is displaying country without any error.

I'am a beginner in react.
have looked many similar answers but not getting any solutions for this.

above is the code in APP.js

I referred the answer in
[Populate two dropdown based on selection in another 1 in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239766/populate-two-dropdown-based-on-selection-in-another-1-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understanding the purpose of your array filter

```
const view = VIEWS.filter(({country}) => country === countryVal )[0]
```

but i'm pretty sure you will not get an object with a "states" property who can be iterated like this :

```
{view.states.map(m => <option>{m}</option>)}
```

are you looking for something like this :

```
{view[0].states.map(m => <option>{m}</option>)}
```

?

Comment: I referred the answer in the question which I now updated above..I made some changes to the answer for my need

Comment: I actually want each of the state array to get populated in state select menu on country selection

Answer (score 0):

got the problem finally.

I forgot to set the  countryVal:'' value in VIEWS for empty country selection.

I modified the VIEW as follows and it worked fine.

```
const VIEWS = [
      {
        country: '', 
        states: [''] 
      },
      {
        country: 'India', 
        states: ['Kerala', 'Karnataka','Tamil nadu'] 
      }, {
        country: 'America', 
        states: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
      }, {
        country: 'Africa', 
        states: ['test4', 'test5', 'test6']
      }
    ]
```

thanks for the replay guys