# How to populate 2 selects based on first select option using API data - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a task with 3 selects, where first select need to be name of an user, and when user is selected, next two selects get options about selected user.

I am new to React and I am not sure how to do this. There is a code of what i have tried so far.

Is there a simple way to complete this task by not using Redux for React? Thank you in advance!

```js
class Users extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            contacts: [],
            country: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }

    fetchData() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(parsedJSON => parsedJSON.map(user => (
                {
                    name: `${user.name}`,
                    username: `${user.username}`,
                    email: `${user.email}`
                }
            )))
            .then(contacts => this.setState({
                contacts,
                isLoading: false
            }))
            .catch(error => console.log('error is: ', error))
    }


    render() {
        const {contacts} = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="filter-container col-6 mt-5">
                        <select name="" id="" onChange={this.onChangeHandler}>
                            {
                                this.state.contacts.map(contact => {
                                    const { email, name } = contact;
                                    return <option key={email} value={name}>{name}</option>
                                })
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="filter-results col-6">
                        <p>
                            {/* this is where filtered data render */}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Since, you are trying to do a side effect it is recommended to use a library like, redux with middleware as `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga`.

But for your case you can use the hooks for example. [Here](https://tinkerylabs.com/ajax-calls-with-react-hooks/) have a look

Comment: I have found an answer on similar post, but I need logic with using an API. Here is what I have found- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239766/react-how-to-populate-two-dropdowns-based-on-selection-in-another)

Comment: can be done using `setState` only, just define `onChangeHandler` to make next api call (and another `setState` with results)

Answer (score 0):

> This is fairly easy you just have to find the selected user among
>   all contacts and maintain the selected User

```
class Users extends Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
         isLoading: true,
         contacts: [],
         country: [],
         selectedUser: {}
      };
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(parsedJSON =>
            parsedJSON.map(user => ({
               name: `${user.name}`,
               username: `${user.username}`,
               email: `${user.email}`
            }))
         )
         .then(contacts =>
            this.setState({
               contacts,
               isLoading: false
            })
         )
         .catch(error => console.log("error is: ", error));
   }


   onChangeHandler = e => {
      // get selected user
      const selectedName = e.target.value;
      // search it in existing contacts 
      const selectedUser = this.state.contacts.find(user =>  user.name === selectedName);
      // if user found then maintain it as selected user
      if (!!selectedUser) {
         this.setState({
            selectedUser
         });
      }
   };

   render() {
      const { contacts, selectedUser, isLoading } = this.state;

      return (
         <div>
            {/* if all users all loaded */
            !isLoading && (
               <div className="container">
                  <div className="row">
                     <div className="filter-container col-6 mt-5">
                        <select name="" id="" onChange={this.onChangeHandler}>
                           {this.state.contacts.map(contact => {
                              const { email, name } = contact;
                              return (
                                 <option key={email} value={name}>
                                    {name}
                                 </option>
                              );
                           })}
                        </select>
                     </div>
                     <div className="filter-results col-6">
                        <p>
                           {/* this is where filtered data render */}
                           {Object.keys(selectedUser).length > 0 && (
                              <pre>
                                 <h3>Filtred Data :</h3>
                                 <span>Name: {selectedUser.name}</span>
                                 <br />
                                 <span>UserName: {selectedUser.username} 
                                  </span>
                                 <br />
                                 <span>Email: {selectedUser.email}</span>
                              </pre>
                           )}
                        </p>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            )}
         </div>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

---

Code snippet https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-filtering-users

I hope this work you!!